# Foursquare checkins

Tags: foursquare, checkin

Any idea what can I do to get only the checkins from a specific venue?

If i use it like:

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/VENUE_ID?oauth_token=XXX
```

i get everything about the venue, and I only need the checkins.

Anyone has a solution? Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can see who is currently checked in via the /venues/herenow endpoint. Historical check-in information for a venue is only available to the venue manager via the foursquare merchant platform